# What is meant by "finished with a super 'DAH'"?

Tags: beelzebub

In chapter 196 of Beelzebub, after beating Nasubi, Oga buried Nasubi's doppelgangers into the ceiling, as shown in the image below.

Is there a meaning in the position of the bodies (with the reference of "super DAH")? Or is it just meant to be random?

[image: Dah]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corpses form the [Katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Table_of_katakana) character "ダ", which is pronounced as "Da".

Comment: The scene before this where he's going against all the Nasubis is probably a parody of Kenshiro's so-called "dadada" warcry.